# custom_variation_price stopped working in product catalog

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using the following snippet to show only the maximum price of a variation product:

```php
add_filter ('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2); 
function custom_variation_price ($price, $product) {
    return wc_price ($product->get_variation_price ('max'));
}
```

It worked perfectly earlier, but since a recent update it went wrong. Now it works on the single product page, but not in the product catalog. The product catalog shows “€0.00 – €149.00”, the single product page shows only “€149.00” correctly.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this? WordPress version: 6.4.3, WooCommerce version: 8.6.1.

Comment: Your code still works perfectly in last WooCommerce version on shop, archive pages and single product pages… So this issue is related to something else making trouble…

Comment: Thanks a lot, this actually helped me resolving the issue. It was caused by the "Discount Rules and Dynamic Pricing for WooCommerce" plugin that modified the price back after the snippet. Turning the "Change Display Price" option off resolved the issue.